# Pn junction under forward bias

Tags: batteries, circuit-analysis, pn-junction

If two batteries are connected such that positive terminal of one is in contact with negative terminal of other then we add the potentials so the potential will then be their sum.

Similarly if a battery is connected to a pn junction diode such that positive terminal is connected to negative side of junction potential
(ie.connected to p type) then why don't we add their potentials? 
Isn't junction potential similar to the second battery as in the first case?

Please explain it at level of a high school student.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the big different between battery and diode is:

Battery is Generator but diode is kind of Electrical load .

some device exist which name is voltmeter you can check component voltage with it if you connect two head of connector of voltmeter to battery you will see voltage on it . if you connect the voltmeter to diode you cant see any thing and the value of voltmeter display is 0 (zero).

diode have voltage break about 0.7v for silicon diode and 0.3v for germanium diode this is call Gamma voltage .
Nature Gamma voltage is not generator type . it's just waist circuit voltage like under picture .
diode can have voltage but it need battery first.
[image]